# Weird about cell.detailTextLabel!.text not showing properly (only show after select it)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell

I set my tableview to `Subtitle` and set tableview cell like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    var row = indexPath.row
    var section = indexPath.section

    if (subtitleExist) {
        cell.textLabel!.text = myTitle
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = mySubtitle
    }else{
        cell.textLabel!.text = myAnotherTitle
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = ""
    }
}
```

And then the result come to this when I first roll down, no subtitle for some (random?) cell:

[image: no subtitle for some cell]

And after I touch the cell, it appears:

[image: appears after touch it]

So how can I solve it? Thanks!

**Edit:**

Here's my full testing code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var myTableView: UITableView!

    var data : [String]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        data = []
        data.append("I")
        data.append("WILL")
        data.append("APPEND")
        data.append("LOTS")
        data.append("LOTS")
        data.append("LOTS")
        data.append("LOTS")
        data.append("LOTS")
        data.append("LOTS")
        data.append("LOTS")
        data.append("LOTS")
        data.append("LOTS")
        data.append("LOTS")
        data.append("OF")
        data.append("DATA")
        data.append("HERE")
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellSubtitle") as? UITableViewCell

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "CellSubtitle")
        }

        var row = indexPath.row

        cell!.detailTextLabel!.text = ""

        if (row >= 7) {
            cell!.textLabel!.text = data[indexPath.row]
            cell!.detailTextLabel!.text = "My Subtitle Text"
        }else{
            cell!.textLabel!.text = data[indexPath.row]
        }

        return cell!
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your `tableView:selectedRowAtIndexPath:` function if you have one? Also are you sure the prototype cells are of the right type?

Comment: @ManavGabhawala my prototype cells's style is set to `Subtitle` from Storyboard. And my code is edited in question. :)

Comment: If you are using a built in cell maybe it's a better option to initialize the cell inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. Can you try something like this instead: `UITableViewCell(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: textCellIdentifier)` and then use the result of that to setup the cell instead of dequeuing the cells? Maybe this will work better. If it does I'll move this comment to an answer.

Comment: have you checked  `mySubtitle` is getting the subtitle where have you set `mySubtitle`

Comment: @HamzaAnsari yes, I can get it's subtitle from codes.

Comment: @Arefly, did you tried this in  a separate project, it is working as expected to me.

Comment: @HamzaAnsari it's in a separate project :(

Comment: i tried your testing code and its working fine subtitles are shown after row 7

Comment: @Arefly, are you using categories ?

Comment: @NeverHopeless I'm using on Section

Comment: May be i should be a bit more clear, i am talking about this: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/objective-c-categories--mobile-10648 .So have you used categories in your project for UITableView, UITableViewCell or any other class ?

Comment: @NeverHopeless I guess I haven't. The code I post in my question is the full code of a new project.

Comment: Which iOS SDK are you using ?

Comment: @NeverHopeless iOS SDK 8.4

Comment: Problem is not re-producable. May be if we can get your test proj ?

Comment: @NeverHopeless ok, here's my whole project: http://www.wikiupload.com/AEQ5LZ9EH2WQYVU

Comment: Everything seems to work OK as expected, i am getting subtitle for row number 7 or greater rows, no text hiding issue. Try deleting app from simulator or resetting your simulator using `iOS Simulator->Reset Content  & Settings...`.

Comment: @NeverHopeless sorry... that's the wrong file. The one not working is: http://www.wikiupload.com/B3KXRVW7RJU3RV8

Answer (score 0):

you want to continue manually initializing the cells, you can use the following dequeue method instead. Then as far as initializing the detailTextLabel goes, you don't have to. It's built into the cell, and by specifying that the cell's style should be subtitle, that label will be set up for you.

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellSubtitle") as? UITableViewCell

    var row = indexPath.row
    var section = indexPath.section

    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = ""

    if (subtitleExist) {

        cell.textLabel!.text = myTitle

        if(mySubtitle.length > 0)
        {
             cell.detailTextLabel!.text = mySubtitle
        }

    } else {

        cell.textLabel!.text = rowText           
    }
}
```

Comment: i change my code to `var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier) as! UITableViewCell` but the result is still same :(

Comment: how to reuse the cell exactly?

Comment: like `if (cell == nil) {
    cell = UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier:cellReuseIdentifier)
  }`

Comment: check once your code and data might be some small mistake there debug it and check it

Comment: checked and everything is right. I will post my full test code in question :(

Comment: i just change `cell` to `var cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: textCellIdentifier)`. It's works fine but I guess it's not a good way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be with the re-usability of cells. Try following steps:

1. Goto Storyboard
2. Select TableView
3. Attributes Inspector tab
4. Change `Prototype Cells` to 0 then reset back to 1.
5. Save and run

See if this solves your problem.

Comment: still same result... :(

Comment: and with zero prototype cells ? since cell is being construct by code.

Comment: it's works... so the cell need to be created inside code?

Comment: Basically, you are constructing cell inside code as well as defined in UI, so it is creating trouble in re-usability somehwere. If you are creating cell from code, then remove cell from storyboard XIB.